# jQuery onLoad handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, blogengine.net

I'm using jQuery and trying to initialize the tabs jQuery UI widget. The problem I have is that my onload handler isn't called. I have a javascript include with the following:

```
jQuery.ready(function () {
    alert(0);
    $('.autoTabs').tabs();
    $('.dateField').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/Images/calendar_16.png', direction: 'left', buttonImageOnly: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $('.timeField').timepicker({});
});
```

Yet when the document loads, nothing is shown, and there are no reported errors in IE or Firefox.

I've used jQuery extensively in the past and I'm baffled as to why this isn't working. The page in question is at http://chickenping.com/viewrecipes.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do either `$(function(){ alert(0); })` or `$(document).ready(function(){alert(0);})`

Comment: @jball I didn't know that.  How come?

Comment: I was wrong - I missed the missing ()... `$().ready(handler)` will work, bit the  OP's `$.ready(handler)` won't

Comment: @jball No worries.  I thought maybe there were some dark jquery secrets that I was unaware of.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was just blind to this.

Comment: @Echilon it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
//or $(document).ready
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert(0);
        $('.autoTabs').tabs();
        $('.dateField').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/Images/calendar_16.png', direction: 'left', buttonImageOnly: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        $('.timeField').timepicker({});
    });
```

Since your asking for the document to finish loading

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` should do the trick